# "automata" and "finite-automata"

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

Do we need the prefix "finite" for the tag [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata)? Is there a reason not to use the shorter [automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata)? Do we need both of them?

I suggest that we merge the [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata) into [automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata) labels a subset of the questions about [automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata) that is big and important enough to warrant its own tag. In particular, more applied askers may find it more fruitfuil to navigate only questions about finite automata, without having to sift through questions about [intellectual games](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110/determining-capabilities-of-a-min-heap-or-other-exotic-state-machines).

Therefore, I suggest we keep [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata).

Comment: looking at the question tagged with them I see that we need the tag.

Answer (score 4):

We absolutely need [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata). Finite automata are usually taught as DFAs and NFAs. There are other kinds of automata that are called automata but are not finite automata in the finite state sense, such as [pushdown-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pushdown-automata). A tag [automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata) would have a more general meaning, most of the audience would not expect it to mean finite automata
only.

I don't see any point in having [automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata) on a question also tagged [finite-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata) when the question is specifically about finite automata and regular language theory. The only usefulness I see to [automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata) is when the question is about models of computation, and even then, I don't know if it's that useful: isn't [computability](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computability) enough?

Retag, or burninate?

Comment: looking at the list of questions tagged with these 3 I am leaning towards Raphael's answer. Formal-languages, automata-theory, and computability-theory are closely related but distinct topics. Maybe we should rename [tag:automata] to [tag:automata-theory]? My main concern is that right now the tags are too similar and their use is not consistent. Making [tag:automata] a synonym for [tag:finite-automata] can also be fine, [tag:formal-languages] tag would be sufficient as subject categorization.

Comment: I think we should keep [tag:automata] because [tag:computability] feels a bit too broad. Renaming to [tag:automata-theory] can work, I guess, but is not necessary.